# Descent Theorem Problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> If $A$ is a finitely generated $K$-algebra which is a domain, and $p_0 \subsetneqq \cdots \subsetneqq p_t$ a chain of prime ideals, how I can show that if $F$ is the field of fractions of $A$ and $d$ is the transcendence degree of $F$ over $K$ then $t \le d$?

I think that I have to apply the descent theorem for prove this result, but I don't know how. Someone can help me? Thanks.

The theorem of descent is:

Let $B\subseteq A$ be an integral extension of integral domains with $B$ normal. Let $p_1 \supseteq \cdots \supseteq p_n$ be a chain of prime ideals of $B$ and $P_1 \supseteq \cdots \supseteq P_m$ a chain of prime ideals of $A$ such as $P_i \cap B = p_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq m<n$. Then the chain $P_1 \supseteq \cdots \supseteq P_m$ can be extended to a chain $P_1 \supseteq \dots \supseteq P_m \supseteq \cdots \supseteq P_n$ such as $P_i \cap B = p_i$ for all $1\leq i \leq n$.

Comment: I don't know, I think that I have to apply this theorem but I don't know how do it.

Comment: The "theorem of descent" is often called the "Going-Down Theorem". And yes, you can use it to prove the result by considering $B$ a Noether normalization of $A$.